# How to ask if the user wants to re-run the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, user-input

I have no idea how to ask users if they want to restart the program again and enter with a new file. I want to ask if the user wants to re-run the program or just terminate it. What's the easiest way to do that? The program is below:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import re
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path




data_folder = Path(input("type the path you would like to use: "))
file_to_open = data_folder / input("insert the file you would like to   use with its extension: ")
with open(file_to_open) as f:
    words = word_tokenize(f.read().lower())
with open ('Fr-dictionary2.txt') as fr:
    dic = word_tokenize(fr.read().lower())


l=[ ]
errors=[ ]
out_file=open("newtext.txt","w")

for n,word in enumerate (words):
    l.append(word)
    if word == "*":
        exp = words[n-1] + words[n+1]
        print("\nconcatenation error:", exp)
        if exp in dic:
            l.append(exp)
            l.append("$")
            errors.append(words[n-1])
            errors.append(words[n+1])
        else:
            continue


for i, w in enumerate(l):
    if w == "*":
        l.remove(l[i-1])
    else:
        continue
for i, w in enumerate(l):
    if w == "$":
        l.remove(l[i+1])
    else:
        continue

text=' '.join(l)
print('\n\n',text)
e=len(errors)
print('\n',e/2,'WORDS CONCATENATED IN TEXT',errors)

user=input('\nREMOVE * AND $ FROM TEXT? Type "Y" for yes or "N" for   no:')


for x in l:
    if user=='Y' and x=='*':
        l.remove(x)
    elif user=='Y' and x=='$':
        l.remove(x)
    else:
        continue

final_text=' '.join(l)
print('\n\n', final_text)

user2=input('\nWrite text to a file? Type "Y" for yes or "N" for no:')


if user2 =='Y':
    out_file.write(final_text)
    out_file.close()
    print('\nText named "newtext.txt" written to a file'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic structure you are looking for:

```
def some_function_you_want_to_repeat():
    print("Do some stuff")
    choice = input("Do you want to do this again? | yes/no")
    if choice == 'yes':
        some_function_you_want_to_repeat()


some_function_you_want_to_repeat()
```

Comment: but I want to repeat the whole program, do I have to use def () for each part of the program and then call each def() defined if the user's answer is yes?

Comment: No, you can make one function, maybe called something like `def main()` and call it once at the bottom of the script and at the end ask if the user wants to try again, just like in the example.

Comment: Does that mean that my program will be under this main def() function?

Comment: Everything that you want to have *repeated*. That could be the whole program.